# Вывод тег как на ХэшКоде

Tags: css

Привет друзья
Хочу сделать вывод тег как на этом сайте.

[image: img1]

Каким должен быть css код?

```
div.tagcloud a {
    display: block;
background: #ededed;
text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

такой вариант меня не устраивает:
вот что получается

[image: img2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zQ2NY/

http://jsfiddle.net/zQ2NY/1/ - динамические

Comment: Спасибо, можно блоком? пробовал display: block, некрасиво выходит

Comment: ставьте переносы строк. И поиграйтесь с margin